# How can I get grep to work in a for loop correctly? Command works outside of loop

Tags: bash, sed, grep, sh, tr

I have a bunch of xml files I need to cut a section out of and process it converting to hex.  I have a command that works from the command line

```
grep -oE '<y min="0.0" max="15.0">[^<]*</y>' AP22S.xml  | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' | tr " " "\n" | grep -v [a-zA-Z] | xargs printf '%x' > AP22S.blob
```

When placed in this loop though

```
for f in $FILES
do
grep -oE "<y min=\"0.0\" max=\"15.0\">[^<]*</y>" "$f" \
  | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' \
  | tr " " "\\n" \
  | grep -v "[a-zA-Z]" \
  | xargs printf '%x' \ 
> $TARGET_DIR"$f"".blob"
done
```

It does nothing.  What am I missing?

Sample from section of XML I want

> <y min="0.0" max="15.0">0 0 0 0 0 0 2 4 6 7 8 9 10 10 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12 12 11 11 10 10 10 9 8 7 6 0 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 8 8 9 9 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 2 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 10 11 11 10 11 11 10 11 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 8 8 8 8 8 8 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 0 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 9 10 10 9 10 10 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 0 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 0 9 9 9 9 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 4 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 4 4 4 4 3 3 2 1 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 4 1 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0</y>

Sample output

> 000000246789aabbbccccccbbaaa98760444556678899aaabbbbcccccccccccccc2cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccbbbbbbbbbabbabbabaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa99999999888888777776666067777777777888888888999999999999aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa9aa9aa99999999099999990999988888888888888877777776666655435555555544144444434444444444044443321344444444444444404444444444443444444444444434133444444444444455555555555555555555555555555555555555055555555550554444444444444444433333333333333333333333323222222222211111111111000101000

Comment: That's a buggy way to iterate over output from `find` in the first place.

Comment: First select the right tool for a task. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: ...and consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: Add AP22S.xml and your desired output to your question.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind re: correctly/robustly iterating over content from `find`. And fix the issues that shellcheck finds on that count.

Comment: You seem to be missing `;` between `$FILES` and `do`, also before `done`. Is that a copy/pasting error?

Comment: Ok didn't know about shellchecker.net  thanks.  Fixed the issues it had. Don't have access to xml parser at the moment, trying to get IT to approve adding anything is a chore so i tried to work around it.  Added sample input and desired output from the command when run from command line.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

There's a very subtle error in the line

```
  | xargs printf '%x' \
```

- a space after the backslash. This not only forms a second argument to `printf`, but also detaches the output redirection in the following line from the pipeline, so that nothing gets written to the output file.

By the way, if you want the output files not to be named for example `AP22S.xml.blob`, but rather `AP22S.blob`, you can remove the original extension with `>$TARGET_DIR${f%.xml}.blob`.